# XPath: How to select child node using value of second child node

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have data in xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmlroot>
    <groups>
        <group>
            <object>
                <symbol>O.01</symbol>
                <name>object 1</name>
                <selected>false</selected>
            </object>
            <group>
                <object>
                    <symbol>O.02</symbol>
                    <name>object 2</name>
                    <selected>false</selected>
                </object>
                <group>
                    <object>
                        <symbol>O.03</symbol>
                        <name>object 3</name>
                        <selected>false</selected>
                    </object>
                </group>
            </group>
        </group>
        <group>
            <object>
                <symbol>O.04</symbol>
                <name>object 4</name>
                <selected>false</selected>
            </object>
            <object>
                <symbol>O.05</symbol>
                <name>object 5</name>
                <selected>false</selected>
            </object>
        </group>
    </groups>
</xmlroot>
```

I would like to perform the following operation on this xml in my Java app: if I get a specific object symbol, I should mark this object by setting the 'true' value on the `<selected>` element
i.e. if I get symbol value = "O.03" then fragment of xml should look like this:

```
                    <object>
                        <symbol>O.03</symbol>
                        <name>object 3</name>
                        <selected>true</selected>
                    </object>
```

So I should find the element `<symbol>` with the indicated value, then its parent node and then the childnode of this parent - the `<selected>` element - and set it to the right value.
I'd like to do this to make it work no matter how much the `<object>` tag is nested inside the `<group>` tags

I try to do it using XPath, like this (Java code):

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    symbol = "O.03";
    nodepath = "//selected AND /parent::symbol[text()='" + symbol + "']";
    Element e = (Element) xpath.evaluate(nodepath, doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

but it does not work :-(

Is this possible with single .evaluate call at all ?

Thanks for help.

koli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible with single .evaluate call at all ?

It is possible to *select* the element in one call. To change its value, you have to use another instruction.

For example, to select the `<selected>` element from the `object` with a specific symbol value use

```
nodepath = "//object[symbol/text()='" + symbol + "']/selected";
```

After evaluating this expression, change the value of the (first) result `Element` to `true`.

Comment: works perfect :-) , value changed with 'e.setTextContent("true");'